# Add additional information (meta) to HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, metadata

I have many HTML elements (e.g. buttons) that all do the same thing when pressed, but I need the id of each element for the event. Is there a good way to store the information, so my script can determit wich button exactly got pressed?

My code looks something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('.myButtons').click(function() {
        var id = // the id of the button
        // do stuff with the id
    });
    }); 
    </script>
</head> class='default'
<body>
<input type='button' class='myButtons' value='Button Id 1' />
<input type='button' class='myButtons' value='Button Id 2' />
<!-- lots more ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

If I save it as an number in the `id`- or `class`-attribut, I won't be able to be sure that the element is unique and the id/class won't be very informative. If you save it as a combination of label and id, e.g. `button14`, I would need to parse the string before getting the id. This isn't a very nice way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an HTML5 data attribute to store this information, for example:

```
<input type='button' class='myButtons' value='Button Id 1' data-my-id="foo" />
<input type='button' class='myButtons' value='Button Id 2' data-my-id="bar" />
```

And read the attribute with

```
$('.myButtons').click(function() {
    var id = this.getAttribute("data-my-id");
});
```

Instead of `getAttribute` you can of course use jQuery if you prefer:

```
var id = $(this).attr("data-my-id");
```

Comment: +1 Perfect. @Frithjof: FYI, you may get people telling you to use `.data` to get the information. That *works*, use it if you like, but it's misleading and assymetical, ***carefully*** read the [`data` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for why so you know what you're using if you choose to go that way.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks. I considered mentioning `.data` and that it offers nothing in this case, but decided to just let it slide. Frankly I 'd have preferred `.data` to not have that piece of magic behavior at all.

Comment: @ Jon: Yeah, I'm with you on that. Maybe as an explicit thing, e.g., `$("some selector").dataInitFromAttributes();`.

Comment: .data (IMO) is worth mentioning. Hopefully one day soon ie will support it native (element.dataset) and we can all rejoice.

Answer (score -1):

or you can tring something like this

```
$(function(){
    $(".myButtons").click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("value"));
    });
});
```

Comment: That would return the displayed label of the button, but the name can be completely random.